# Google Cloud storage PUT with API KEY using node.js

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I am trying to put a file into Google Cloud Storage by using API KEY.  What is the proper way to do it?

I am put into an address of 
"https://storage.googleapis.com/my_test?key=AIzaSyD5TnLAX6N_xAuSudUYSS6k1j8UxfaV9YN"

However, I got an error saying I am missing a required header.  What should be the proper way to do this?

Thanks.

Server responded with: MissingSecurityHeader; Your request was missing a required header: Authorization

Comment: By the way, you may find the [gcloud-node project](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcloud-node) useful for doing Google Cloud Storage from node.js.

Answer (score 0):

An API key is not an authentication mechanism. See the [Authentication](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/authentication) page for the supported authentication methods. Namely:

- OAuth 2.0
- Cookies
- Service Accounts